# Pycharm only reading name of csv file and not data inside csv

Tags: python, csv

```
with open('CSV_Files/Players.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader('Players.csv', delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        print(row)
```

I am trying to read a csv file to the console but instead I am only getting:

```
['P']
['l']
['a']
['y']
['e']
['r']
['s']
['.']
['c']
['s']
['v']
```

How can I get the data to be printed?

Comment: You're opening the file `as csv_file` but then you're not using this variable `csv_file`.

Comment: How is PyCharm involved in this? Have you read the csv docs? I'm voting to close this, since the only issue appears to be the incorrect use of a library function.

Comment: Should be ` csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')`